# Disable Combo box of user control in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, user-controls

I have one user control which contains Two comboobx, six textbox and 4 labels.I
I have added this user control in main window xaml like this:

```
<Grid Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,156,0,0" Name="grid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="320"  />
    <Grid Height="Auto" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,156,0,0" Name="grid2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="320"  />
    <Grid Height="Auto" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,156,0,0" Name="grid3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="320" />
    <Grid Height="Auto" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,156,0,0" Name="grid4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="320" />
```

I have Created view model for UserControl which name is UserControlViewModel and main window has view model which name is MainViewModel.

I have created object of usercontrol in mainViewModel.

My question on run time I have to disable combo box1 from UserControl in grid2 and grid4.

Comment: Your requirement is not a question. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can give name to your usercontrol in mainwindow and then can access any element of your usercontrol and then can set  any property of your usercontrol as below.

1. Please give name to your usercontrol which is resides in your mainwindow.

   x:Name="MyUserControl"
2. In Code Behind, Now you can set combobox1 disabled like this.

   MyUserControl.grid2.combobox1.IsEnabled = false;

   MyUserControl.grid4.combobox1.IsEnabled = false;

Comment: Thanks I got my answer.

Comment: For me it worked by naming the combobox instead of the userControl.